# LINQ fill nested list of Object from query results

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am joining two tables `Race` and `Odds` (joined on `RaceID`) and would like to create an object for each Race with its nested odds. Via LINQ I am able to group the query results into objects but can't populate the **nested** `Odds list` for each `Race`. Any ideas?

Ideally, I should have

```
obj[0] with RaceID = 1, Odds{1,2,3}
obj[1] with RaceID = 2, Odds{4,5,6,7}
```

etc

```
Public Class Race
   Private RaceID As Integer
   Private Name As String
   'other properties here 
   Private Odds As New List(Of Odds)
End Class

Public Class Odds
    Private OddsID As Integer
    Private Odds As System.Nullable(Of Decimal)   
    Private RaceID As Integer  
    'other properties here 
End Class
```

#### My function

```
Dim objRace As New List(Of Race)
Using context As IDataContext = DataContext.Instance()
    Dim repository = context.GetRepository(Of Race)()
    objRace = repository.Find("SELECT Odds.OddsID, Odds.Odds, Odds.Name, Odds.Type, Odds.DateUTC, Odds.WebsiteName, Odds.RaceID AS RaceID, Race.RaceID AS RaceID,
                          Race.Name AS RaceName, Race.RaceDate, Race.Location, Race.URL, Race.PortalID AS PortalID, Race.RaceTime
    FROM Odds RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                          Race ON Odds.RaceID = Race.RaceID
    WHERE (Race.PortalID = @0)",  PortalId)
End Using
```

LINQ to get objects

```
Dim result = objRace.GroupBy(Function(records) records.RaceID).[Select](Function(r) New Race() With {
    .RaceID = r.Key
    .Odds = ' <------ **somehow populate this nested list**
}).ToList()
```

my query results:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

The `r` should be a implementation of [`IGrouping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2). This contains a `Key` that you are using for your `RaceID` and it is a [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1) itself.

So you can store the `Odds` by calling `r.ToList()` or `r.ToArray`. How ever you want to store them.

I just noticed that you already create the list instance for your `Odds` in the constructor. You may want to change this, so you can put the collection in directly using the `With` initialisation.

Comment: the r is a List(Of Race) not List(Of Odds)